# ASP.NET: CalendarExtender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been doing this for an hour yet can't find any solution on how to fix this. CalendarExtender not working.

HEre's my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NyxsysTicketingSytem.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="~/Styles/ajax__calendar_container.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate"> </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I already add it in my reference. My Ajaxcontroltoolkit version is 4.1.7.1213

Or if there is another way not to use Ajax? I just need to display a calendar when textbox or a button clicked.

And also tried some tutorials yet still not working.

I also tried this one yet not working just giving me an error.

```
 <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your web.config,

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <pages>
          <controls>
              <add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
          </controls>
      </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Edit:

Remove `ScriptManager` and add the `ToolkitScriptManager` from the Visual Studio Toolbox window under Ajax Control Toolkit tab

Comment: make sure you're adding `pages section` under `system.web` root level and check typo if any.